# generating UUID creation token for EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, token, uuid, amazon-efs

Is this sufficient for generating a UUID for using as a creation token for AWS CLI EFS ~ Elastic File System? Assuming you've been granted appropriate permissions.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('c3505347-ec30-4f74-9597-e4180de6c56f')
>>>
```

Comment: better yet JavaScript Fiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/xg7tek9j/7/

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine. If the file system made with that token already exists, a `FileSystemAlreadyExists` error will be returned. Ideally you should keep track of tokens you've sent over the wire at least until the EFS has been successfully created.

Comment: Thanks again. There's no real clarity peering through the looking glass at the docs on certain things.